# CLang Python bindings: parse if statement node

Tags: c++, python-3.x, llvm-clang

I want to parse

```
if (email.find ("@")! = String :: npos) {cout << "Correct"; }
```

hild nodes get so

```
node.getchildren ()
```

BUT CLang not find if statement node, because in the condition there

```
email.find ("@")! = String :: npos
```

Now this statement

```
if (a == b) {// do something }
```

it finds no problems.

HOW IT WORKS? help me please.

**My code**

Recursive method of tree traversal

```
    def search_in_ast(self, node, look):
    """
    Поиск однотипных узлов в синтаксическом дереве
    Args:
        node: узел дерева, в котором будет осуществляться рекурсивный поиск
        look: массив искомых представлений узлов (VAR_DECL, FUNCTION_DECL и др) node.kind

    Returns: массив найденных узлов

    """
    nodes_decl = []
    # n = list(node.get_tokens())
    if node.kind in look:
        nodes_decl.append(node)

    # рекурсивный обход дочерних узлов
    for c in node.get_children():

        # обход дочерних узлов выполняется только в файле - main, чтобы не тратить время на стандартные инклюды
        file_name = c.location.file.name.decode("utf-8")
        if file_name == self.path_to_source_code:
            new_vars = self.search_in_ast(c, look)
            if new_vars:
                nodes_decl = nodes_decl + new_vars
    return nodes_decl
```

So getting the right type of nodes

```
match_nodes = [clang.cindex.CursorKind.IF_STMT]
nodes = self.search_in_ast(node, match_nodes)
```

Comment: I think you need to show your code that tries to parse the expression - my guess is that you are making assumptions on how the expression is calulated.

Comment: added my code in python